# How to find the surface integral of Torus intersecting with cylinder ??

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, surface-integrals

> Let $T$ be the torus obtained by revolving the circle
>
> {$(x,0,z)| (x-3)^2 + z^2 = 1$} about the $z$-axis.
>
> Find the area of the surface obtained by taking the intersection of $T$ with the cylinder {$(x,y,z)|x^2 + y^2 \leq 9$}.

**i am not sure if the domain is right  seen below in the trial**

$\\$

> my trial :

I parametrized the torus :
$r(\theta,\phi) = (~(\cos(\theta)+3)\cos(\phi),(\cos(\theta)+3)\sin(\phi),\sin(\theta)~)$

the intersection is when :

${[(\cos(\theta)+3)\cos(\phi)]}^{2}+{[(\cos(\theta)+3)\sin(\phi)]}^2 \leq 9$

we get : 
$\frac{\pi}{2}\leq \theta \leq \frac{3\pi}{2}$

$0\leq \phi \leq 2\pi$

and we continue with the domain above :

|| $\frac{\partial r}{\partial \theta}$ x $\frac{\partial r}{\partial \phi}$ || = $(\cos(\theta)+3)$

and so :

S = $\iint ds$ = $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}} (\cos(\theta)+3) {~d\theta}{~d\phi}$

Comment: That looks right to me.  What looks incorrect about it to you?

Comment: i am not sure about the domain i found it solving the inequality

Comment: Draw a picture then.  what points on the circle $x= (\cos \theta + 3), x = \sin \theta$ inside the cylinder.... $x\le 3$ by the constraint on the cylinder and $\cos \theta \le 0$